# Логика работы с данными в react приложении

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hook

У меня есть достаточно большой массив объектов(122000 элементов). Я сделал два варианта одного компонента для работы с этими данными:

1) Массив данных находится на сервере. С помощью useEffect(func, []) сразу весь массив подгружается при первом рендере компонента и заносится в константу. Далее, когда пользователь начинает вводить в поле input символы, данные из константы начинают фильтроваться определенным образом(это происходит в обработчике поля input) и на экране появляется список из отфильтрованных элементов массива.

2) Массив также находится на сервере, но при каждом пользовательсом вводе происходит запрос на сервер с дополнительным параметром(тем, что ввел пользователь), и, в соответствии с этим параметром, данные фильтруются на сервере и отправляются на клиент, где отображаются также в виде списка.

Клиент написан на react, сервер на nodejs.

Вопрос: с точки зрения производительности, что будет лучше в данном случае? Один запрос на сервер и работа с данными на клиенте или же множество запросов на сервер и работа с данными на сервере?

Comment: Полагаю под "множество запросов на сервер" имеется ввиду что вы будете брать не весь массив данных, а определенные его части. Если так, тогда это будем лучшим вариантом для клиента, для сервера в общем-то мало что изменится.

Comment: Ну да, определенные его части. Допустим пользователь хочет написать слово moscow в поле input. Он печатает символ m - выполняется запрос на сервер, которому передается символ m, на что сервер отправляет  отфильтрованный в соответствии с этой буквой массив. Далее пользователь печатает букву o - серверу отправляется запрос со строкой mo, на что сервер отвечает отфильтрованным в соответствии с этой строкой массивом. И так далее.

Comment: На слабых устройствах пользователь выхватит хорошие такие лаги( проверенно лично ), если вы будете каждый раз фильтровать такое количество элементов.

Comment: Над алгоритмом фильтрации данных я буду разбираться чуть позже, сейчас нужно решить, где этот алгоритм будет лучше разместить. Вы рекомендуете на сервере?

Comment: Как и в предыдущих двух сообщениях, я рекомендую на сервере.

Comment: Окей, спасибо.!

Comment: Думаю лучше на сервере, - для того чтобы реализовать сценарий когда результат фильтра огромный (и не требуется в выпадающем списке показывать 1К отобранных позиций) В этом случае с сервера можно присылать первые 10 + строку "еще 1К подходящих вариантов" и пару последних ...

Comment: Интересное решение, я поэкспериментирую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучшим вариантом реализации поиска является использование задержки запросов на клиенте и принятие небольшого объекта от сервера.

То есть, на клиенте по мере ввода пользователем символов на сервер отправляются запросы поиска. Запросы с клиента отправляются при остановке пользователем ввода более чем на 2 секунды к примеру и минимум раз в 4 секунды, если поисковой запрос длинный. Для этого можно использовать [use-debounce](https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce).

Ответ от сервера должен содержать минимум вариантов ответа и не нагружать пользователя. Скажем 10 подходящих вариантов.

Если пользователю недостаточно 10 предоставленных ответов, то он может воспользоваться кнопкой ещё, загрузив ещё варианты.